# passing rvalue reference into boost::in_place function

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, rvalue-reference

I'm new to rvalue references in C++ and want to learn how to use them in everyday life.
I've got 2 connected questions about popular usecases: using rvalue references with boost::in_place and boost::bind.

1. Using rvalue ref in boost::in_place

Consider a class, with constructor taking rvalue reference as a parameter:

```
struct A
    : boost::noncopyable 
{
    A(int&&){}
};
```

Let's now try to create boost optional variable for this class:

```
void foo(int&& value)
{
    boost::optional<A> opt;
    // some code here 
    opt = boost::in_place(std::forward<int>(value)); //Error!
}
```

What is the right way to pass rvalue ref in such an example. Is there any solution like boost::reference_wrapper for rvalue refs?

1. passing bind functor to function object with rvalue reference

Another common usecase is assigning boost::bind functor object to boost::function object.

```
void foo(int&&)
{
}

void bar()
{
    boost::function<void(int&&)> func;

    int x = 0;
    func = boost::bind(foo, std::move(x)); // Compilation error (a)

    func = boost::bind(foo, _1); // Compilation error too (b)
}
```

I understand that instruction (a) could lead to undefined variable value after first invocation, but instruction (b) even has no such a problem. But how to write this code correctly?

Comment: I do not recommend using C++11 features with a library written for C++03 that is unaware of C++11. Check the documentation to see if such usages are supported, which it isn't to the best of my knowledge for Boost.Optional and Boost.Function.

Comment: Boost library usually uses new features from new standart (even when there was no C++11, only C++0x). I've checked the second example with new native 'bind' and 'function' from C++11 - just the same effect (can't check the first example, as there is no 'optional' in C++11).

Answer (score 0):

boost in_places does not natively support move or r-value references.  However, you can make a new class that inherits from boost::in_place_factory_base, and make your own.  Or you could use an optional that supports emplace functions (like folly::Optional).

I'm not sure I recommend doing it, but you can make a generic overload in boost to handle it, something like this:

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>      
#include <boost/utility/in_place_factory.hpp>
#include <folly/ApplyTuple.h>

namespace boost                                                                      
{                                                                                  
  template<class ... As> 
  struct rvalue_in_place : public in_place_factory_base 
  {
    mutable std::tuple<As...> tup_; 
    rvalue_in_place(As ... as)
      : tup_(std::forward<As>(as)...)
   {
   }                                                                                   
   template< class T >
   void apply ( void* address ) const 
   {
     auto make = [address](As ... as) { new (address) T(std::forward<As>(as)...);  }; 
     folly::applyTuple(make, tup_); 
   }
 };   
 template <class ... As> 
 rvalue_in_place<As&&...> in_place(As && ... a)
 {
   return rvalue_in_place<As&&...>(std::forward<As>(a)...);
 }
}
```

Comment: Thx, @capsterx. I've already found [patch](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/attachment/ticket/1841/14-optional-partial-rvalue.2.patch) for boost::in_place, which works with rvalue. At the same time there were promises to add this ability to boost's release [boost tracker](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/1841)